# JAVA: Storage of numbers?

Tags: java, bit

I'm trying to self-learn Java for the AP exam and I've stumbled upon a section that I don't quite understand.

There is a box divided into 8 sections that represents 8 bits of storage.
The first one has a 0 and the seven boxes that come after have 1s. Why are the possible values from -2^7 - (2^7)-1 which is -128 - 127? Why not just turn on the first bit and make it -2^8 - 2^8? Please explain in the simplest and thorough way possible. I've read some answers online on this, but I do not understand. This is also the first section in my book and they don't explain it well.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you tell if it's a negative number or not?

Comment: Read about [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Answer (score 1):

Its a combinatoric Question. If you have 8 Fingers on your hand, how many possible combinations of Fingers can you show to an other Person? The answer is 2^8. That is 2 * 2^7.
So you have 2^7 Positive Number and 2^7 Negative Numbers BUT you also have to show the Zero. So thats why you have 2^7-1 positive values and 2^7 negative ones and the zero. I hope this explains it well.

Comment: Yup, only thing I'd say to add is the binary representation of -1, 0, and 1.

Comment: I'm still confused about why you changed 2^8 to 2*2^7. Also is 2^7-1 subtracting 1 from the exponent or the result of 2^7?

Comment: 2^8 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 *, so 2^8 = 2^4 * 2^4 = 2^7 * 2. The one is subtracted from the result of 2^7

Answer (score 1):

Java bytes are represented as signed bytes, so the left most bit represents the sign of the number (positive or negative), so there are only 7 bits remaining. If you used all 8 bits (so you could get to 2^8), you could not represent negative numbers.

This [two's complement table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) shows this

Comment: So does a 0 represent positive or negative for the first bit? Also if the first bit is 1 to represent if it is positive or negative wouldn't one of the ranges be 2^8?

Comment: @user1813447 - both of those questions are answered by the linked table.